# Can I put an electric continuous water heater in a bathroom with a walk-in tub?

Tags: water

Have walk in bathtub.  40 gal hot water heater not sufficient to fill tub.  Can I put an electric continuous hot water system in bathroom w/the walk in tub?

Answer (score 5):

Electric on demand water heaters require an incredible amount of power, depending upon your electrical service, may require an expensive upgrade.   Then you have the added cost of the extra water heater itself and it's installation.

I see two potential options for you:

1. turn up the temp on your existing water heater a lot and use a mixing valve to provide safely tempered hot water.  This technique makes the smaller water heater "appear larger", you'll probably need a plumber to do this.
2. Simply replace your existing WH with a larger one.   Most likely no electrical changes would need to be made.

Again:  On demand electric water heaters need a lot of power...for sure a new dedicated circuit.

Comment: This is the answer.  Cranking up the water heater temperature significantly will result in scalding water unless each spigot is changed to a "Delta" style thermostatic mixing valve. Those have a feature to mix in cold water to keep temperatures below scalding.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica I don't think you fully understood my idea.  The mixing valve is installed **AT THE WATER HEATER**  providing tempered hot water as before throughout the home, no other changes needed.   Is it  a perfect solution?   No, but it might be one of the more cost effective ones.  Here is a link to the pros and cons of cranking up the temp on the WH and using a mixing valve. https://www.rheem.com/water-heating/articles/how-a-mixing-valve-can-get-more-out-of-your-water-heater/

Comment: Oh yes, that's much better!  There'd be no limit to water heater temp outside of its rating of course.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can if you have access to the hot water pipes in the bathroom to install the tankless heater, can run two or three heavy cables as dedicated circuits from the heater to your main panel or a sub panel and have an electric service capable of supplying the power to it.

But in agreement with @GeorgeAnderson , there are different options available that will reduce your installation cost and more efficiently help balance the grid, like up sizing your tank.

Comment: Sorry JACK buddy, gotta differ with you on this one.  Electric on demand WHs need A LOT of power, for example, this AO Smith unit needs 117 AMPS at 240V and that only gets you a flow rate of 2.4 GPM.   Many homes only have 100 amp services, but even if they have 200 Amp services, you're looking at using over half the capacity of the service.  Below is link to the unit I'm talking about.   ...more below in next comment.  

https://www.lowes.com/pd/A-O-Smith-Signature-240-Volt-28-kW-2-4-GPM-Tankless-Electric-Water-Heater/1000601621

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson  What happened to just answering the OP's question? I'm not  recommending anything, just answering a question like a good electrical engineer with 30 years in the power industry should do. I am fully aware of everything in your first comment.  That's not what the OP's asking about.  You obviously didn't get for Christmas what you wanted.

Comment: @George it'll be OK though because as fast as those technologies are coming up, smart-panel/smart-grid tech is coming up *even faster*.  Honestly I think we're about to see the end of service upgrades, since you can simply have loads dynamically pre-empt each other. Range > A/C > dryer > water heater > EV > pool heat.  Given that microcontroller tech allowed us to do this in the 1990s, it's shameful that it's taken 30 years more to get into it.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson  Happy  you had a great Christmas and sorry if you were offended by my sarcasm.  Have a happy, safe new year.